# Link external library from different directory

Tags: c, cmake

I'm new to CMake and I'm hoping someone can help me out.

I'm trying to link a library from a different folder. The library is a git repo, and so is my project (I own both). Here is the basic folder structure:

```
Library1/
  build/
  CMakeLists.txt
  library1.h
  library1.c
Project1/
  build/
  CMakeLists.txt
  main.c
```

`Library1/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(Library1 VERSION 0.1)
file(GLOB Sources *.h *.c)
add_library(library1 SHARED ${Sources})
target_include_directories(library1
    INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    )
```

`Project1/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(Project1 VERSION 1.0)
add_library(library1 SHARED IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_target_properties(library1 PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "../Library1/build/Debug/library1.dll")
add_executable(Project1 main.c)
target_link_libraries(Project1 PUBLIC library1)
```

`main.c`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "library1.h"

int main() {
    printf("Hello");
    return 0;
}
```

From `Library1`, running

```
cd build
cmake ..
cmake --build .
```

produces `build/Debug/library1.dll`.

From `Project1`, running the same commands produces the following error:

```
main.c(2,10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file:  
'library1.h': No such file or directory [...]
```

I'm not sure how to set up my `CMakeLists.txt` files correctly to import my library. I might be just missing a line, but I'm not quite sure. Any help would be appreciated! Also, I would rather not hard-code the .dll path into the file.

I'm using CMake for Windows, v3.16.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Project1` executable does not know how to find the header file(s) for `library1`. You can add an include directory for `Project1` by modifying the `Project1/CMakeLists.txt` file to include a [`target_include_directories()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html) call:

```
target_include_directories(Project1 PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../Library1)
```

Comment: Thanks @squareskittles. I added that line to the end of my file, but now I'm getting another error: `LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'library1 
-NOTFOUND.obj'`

Comment: You may try putting `set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS ON)` in your `Library1/CMakeLists.txt` file to export your library's symbols. This should create a `.lib` and `.dll` file. Then, in your other CMake, import the `STATIC` library instead `add_library(library1 STATIC IMPORTED GLOBAL)`, and point to the `.lib` file.

Comment: I just used `STATIC` in both CMake files and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The second makefile is adding the library but not path of the header files (interface) to be used to compile.

Add `include_directories(../Library1)` to the second makefile